# Jquery: list of animations with delay

Tags: jquery, animation, delay

Please consider the following example:
http://jsfiddle.net/vb4af/3/

```
$(".add").click(function (e){
    $(this).parent().animate({width: "70%"}, 400);
    return false;
});

$(".addall").click(function (e){
    $(".add").each(function (){$(this).click().delay(100);});
});
```

I would like to use an add all button to start the animations but with a specific delay.
The sample speak for itself.

Please help.
Regards
J

Answer (score 0):

does this works:

```
$(".add").click(function (e){
    $(this).parent().delay(1000).animate({width: "70%"}, 400);
    return false;
});

$(".addall").click(function (e){
    $(".add").each(function (){$(this).click();});
});
```

Comment: Is not good to add an extra delay before every single animation. This solved my problem: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-adding-a-delay-between-each-function-executions